# Saving `dask.array` as hdf5 dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I've got a `dask.array` spanning multiple hdf5 files. Basically, what I would like to do, is to slice the dataset and store the resulting slice to hdf5. What I've tried so far is basically this:

```
In [1]: import dask.array as da

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [5]: xs = da.from_array(np.linspace(0, 10), chunks=10) # could be from hdf5 files

In [7]: import h5py

In [8]: h5f = h5py.File('/tmp/paul/foo.h5')

In [9]: h5f.create_dataset(name='ham', data=xs)
Out[9]: <HDF5 dataset "ham": shape (50,), type "<f8">
```

This works great. However, when I `da.concatenate` multiple `h5py` datasets, the `create_dataset` function seems to freeze (thread deadlock?). Note that `xs` could be a dataset of (ballpark) 10 GB spanning 10 files of 1 GB each.

What is a sensible way to write `xs` to a `h5py` dataset without resorting to `da.compute` and risking `MemoryError`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the h5py library is converting your dask array into an in-memory numpy array, which is probably not what you want.

Instead, you probably want the store function (see [this section in the documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#numpy-style-slicing))

```
f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5')
d = f.require_dataset('/data', shape=x.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
da.store(x, d)
```

You might also want the to_hdf5 method (see [this section in the documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#hdf5))

```
da.to_hdf5('myfile.hdf5', '/x', x)
```

You should take care to chunk your HDF5 dataset appropriately so that it is aligned with your dask.array chunking.  The `to_hdf5` method will handle this for you if you prefer not to think about it yourself.

Comment: I don’t think it converts to an in-memory array. I tried this with a small file for testing, and it hangs for minutes. Converting an array of ~100 elements to in-memory should finish quickly.